# Arithmetic Overflow at RunningPackages (SSIS) problem

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssis, c#, windows-server

I've developed an SSIS Package with the C# Code.All the Package were running fine.But for the past 2 days, we are experiencing

```
public void Main()
        {
            // TODO: Add your code here
            try
            {
                MessageBox.Show("PAckage Starts");
                Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application app = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application();

                MessageBox.Show("BEFORE ERROR");

                string a=Dts.Variables["System::MachineName"].Value.ToString();
                RunningPackages pkgs = app.GetRunningPackages(null);
               RunningPackages abc = app.GetRunningPackages(a);
                MessageBox.Show("AFTER ERROR");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString());
            }

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
```

[image]

This is my Stack Trace.
I've already browsed regarding this issue but not getting any solution. Some [Reference here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dc5a3584-5cf0-4a4c-b35d-9d80ff8ec149/runningpackages-problem).

Investigating into this with Process Monitor tool. The Issue is coming from **MsDtsSrvr.dll** *(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\DTS\Binn\MsDtsSrvr.dll)*

*Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow. (MsDtsSrvr)*

Unfortunately, this Issue is not happening in other Environments.

Anybody, please guide me to solve this error

Thanks in advance,
Jay

Comment: Please provide more details regarding the package.  What is it doing, any code you care to share, etc.

Comment: Are you sure `MachineName` is correct? Note that (from the example in the documentation) it looks like you can provide `null` instead of a machine name, in which case (I can only assume) it will check the machine the code is running on(?).

Comment: @JohnEisbrener I can easily reproduce the error with the simple code (Updated in my Question)

Comment: @RDFozz I tried with Providing MachineName and also null.Both not working in my case.(See the updated Code in my Question)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be addressed to the vendor's support services.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution.As I've told already this is related to **MsDtsSrvr.dll**

So, I've just Restarted the **MsDtsServer110** Service.

No it works Perfectly